# Column with default value for every record update in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How should we update a column with default value on every update statement in Oracle?

Like last update timestamp should have sysdate for every update statement executed

Comment: Default value for the column is sufficient for Insert we also need the same kind of approach update operation as well. don't want to implement trigger approach

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use for a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SOME_TABLE_BU
  BEFORE UPDATE ON SOME_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP := SYSDATE;
END SOME_TABLE_BU;
```

You can extend this easily to handle inserts by using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SOME_TABLE_BIU
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON SOME_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    :NEW.INSERTED_TIMESTAMP := SYSDATE;
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP := SYSDATE;
  END IF;
END SOME_TABLE_BIU;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: I was thinking of a solution where we give default value provided in table creation or alter script. Triggers is not a best approach for me since we have 100+ tables and do not want go through trigger for everyone. Rather the value can be update from source application itself. 
Much appreciated for help!